# iOS Statusbar from background App

Tags: ios

I have a theoretical question, is it possible to develop an app for IOS, 
part of this App would be a statusbar. Lets say, the App is a stopwatch. When I close the app and for example switch to safari, or to home screen or to any other app I need to have a status bar showing the time from the stopwatch.

Is this possible?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Apple does not allow you to add your own items to the iOS status bar.

When you are running your app, it's possible to hide the status bar and display your own recreation of it using a custom `UIView` (this is how RSS readers display sync progress), but if your app is not in the foreground then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to accomplish exactly what you're looking for on a normal iOS device, but here are some alternative ideas to consider:

You could make a widget that lives in the Today pane in the Notifications dropdown (slide down from top), but this is only visible when you open it. Still, you can access this from almost anywhere and most users probably check it all the time. Plus you can add interface elements to pause, reset, add time, etc.

You could also use local notifications (or push notifications) to periodically notify the user of the time or whatever you want to show (could be annoying, depending on what you're doing). Could also add on to these notifications (e.g. like swiping to the left on a notification, or pulling down on a notification, like a notification from the Messages app where you can enter a reply, or the Mail app, where you can quickly reply or delete an email)

You could also use the red badges on the app icon to indicate certain things, but it is pretty limited.

BONUS: you could require your users to buy an Apple Watch

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, for the physical status bar, sorry to say is, no, you cannot do that with a non-jailbroken phone. No app can give custom UI elements, but you can add a widget in the "Today" view of the Notification Center, or use a `WatchKit` view so time can show up on Apple Watch.